# Accessing values from other class and how to access base class variable

Tags: java

I have tried some codes in java to access variables, my code is as follows

```
class FirstClass {
    public String className = "FirstClass";
    int arg=100;
    private String insideVariable="Private";
}
class SecondClass extends FirstClass{
    public String className="SecondClass";
    public String extend=new FirstClass().className;
}

public class Access {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(new FirstClass().className);
        System.out.println(new SecondClass().className);
        System.out.println(new SecondClass().arg);
        System.out.println(new SecondClass().extend);
    }
}
```

I have following questions,

1. I can able to access className variable values by using **new FirstClass.className** and **new SecondClass().className**, Is this creates object or what is the functions happen here?
2. I'm extending the FirstClass to SecondClass, and i can able to access **arg** variable using **new SecondClass().arg**, now how to access the **className** variable in Base class using extended class?

Comment: Why do you want to do this to start with? If you follow normal best-practices (where fields are private) then it isn't an issue to start with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From outside, you can cast to the base type to access the field:

```
System.out.println(((FirstClass)new SecondClass()).className);
```

Answer (score 3):

In `1.` you are creating anonymous instances using `new` and you access their member `className`.
In `2.` you can use `super.className` **INSIDE** your derived class.

```
class SecondClass extends FirstClass{
    public String className="SecondClass";
    public String extend=new FirstClass().className;

    public void method() {
        String cn = super.className;
    }
}
```

Apart from this possibilities, you are grinding OO-principle of data-hiding to pieces.
If you want to access a base-class member, either make the base-class member `protected` or create `getter/setter`-methods.